# Hide a Panel when GridView is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, panel

I've a GridView inside a Panel that I want to hide when the child is empty because at the moment remains a `fieldset` with the `legend` text and nothing inside.

I've already tried to put something like `Panel.Visible = GridView.Rows.Count > 0` in the `Page_Load` event but it doesn't works well.

How can I obtain the result that I need?

Thank you

Some more details:

If on first load the database table is empty I don't see the `fieldset`, when I add a row the Panel with the GridView doesn't appears; if on first load I have a row I can see the Panel with the GridView, when I delete the unique row anything disapears but never come back even if I insert a new row. I think that the Page_Load is not the right event.

Comment: Can you please share your Page_Load() event with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found my problem...
I've put the FormView for the insert and the GridView in different UpdatePanels, so unified all in the same UpdatePanel and used this code:

```
Panel.Visible = GridView.Rows.Count > 0;
```

in the GridView DataBound event and it worked.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Thank you for not using a boolean response to identify a hard-coded true/false as some of the other answers did.

Answer (score 2):

try this..

**`Panel.Visible = (GridView.Rows.Count > 0?false:true);`**

Comment: Put colon `:` instead of the semi-colon `;`.

Comment: Hello, I've already tried this code and I get Always the same result: if on first load the database table is empty I don't see the `fieldset`, when I add an row the Panel with the GridView doesn't appears; if on first load I have a row I can see the Panel with the GridView, when I delete the unique row anything disapears but never come back even if I insert a new row. I think that the Page_Load is not the right event.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following steps:

1. Check for `Panel.Visible = GridView.Rows.Count > 0` in a late page event such as `Page_PreRender`
2. Add `OnRowDeleted` event in GridView and check for `Panel.Visible = GridView.Rows.Count > 0` if the row deleting is a last row. Also rebind the GridView as `GridView.DataBind()`
3. Add `OnRowCreated` event in GridView and repeat the same process as you did in case of row deletion.

Code:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel.Visible = GridView.Rows.Count > 0;
}

protected void GridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView.DataBind();
    Panel.Visible = GridView.Rows.Count > 0;

}
protected void GridView_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView.DataBind();
    Panel.Visible = GridView.Rows.Count > 0;
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to make your panel visible/invisible based on the Gridview Rows, then its as simple as this :

```
if(GridView.Rows.Count > 0)
    PanelId.Visible = true;
else
    PanelId.Visible = false;
```

But make sure you do this code after you have called the Gridview binding function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: which is exactly what he already wrote, just in a more extensive way

Comment: Hello, the GridView is binded by an ObjectDataSource without any code behind and so I don't know how can I put after binding. Thank you

Comment: After deleting or adding a row, you will have to make sure to check the condition again. `Page_Load` will work. Just check your condition on postback and rebind the GridView to update the row status.